# What is the difference between Beal's Conjecture and Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory

In [Beal's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture), are we assuming that we are allowed to repeat numbers? The conjecture is the following:

> **Beals Conjecture:** If $a^n+b^n = c^n $where $n \geq 2$ and $a,b,c,n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ then $a,b$ and $c$ have a common prime factor.

But isn't this basically the opposite of Fermat's Last Theorem? Or does Fermat's Last Theorem require $a,b,c$ to be distinct?

Comment: A generalization of Fermat's last theorem (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BealsConjecture.html)

Comment: That's not Beals conjecture you've posted.

Comment: Slashdot and Texas Banker, huh?

Answer (score 8):

This is not [Beal's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture).  You have in fact stated Fermat's Last Theorem.  Beal's conjecture states that if $a^x + b^y = c^z$, where $a,b,c > 0$ and $x,y,z > 2$, then $\gcd(a,b,c) \neq 1$.  Fermat's Last Theorem is an [easy corollary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture#Consequences) of Beal's Conjecture.

Answer (score 4):

This is not Beal's conjecture! Beal's conjecture is about $$a^x + b^y = c^z$$ where $x,y,z$ are probably not equal.